# what does docker do if specified user doesn't exist on windows 10

Tags: docker

using docker on windows 10 with WSL I ran this command:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /Users/bob/myJupyter:/home/jovyan/work    bob22/data_mining1
```

however there is no `/User/bob` on my machine. what does it do with the files? did it create a folder named `bob` on my machine somewhere?

it downloaded and runs but I get "permission denied" if I try to make a file in the `/work` folder

Comment: Ah, the joys of WSL2. I tried it and found my files in `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data\tarcache\entries\docker.tar\e254f38e9d226ce5093a835f2f3d520e86850879ae32a6b70fc23b96368790c9\containers\services\docker\rootfs\Users\bob\myJupyter`. You should use Windows filename notation and use `-v C:\Users\bob\myJupyter:/home/jovyan/work`. Then the files will be where you expect.

Comment: That was it, thank you! For whatever reason I had to manually navigate to it. The folder only shows up when the container is running which probably explains why I couldn't create anything in `/work`